# Suppose $f$differentiable with $f (0) = 0$ and $f (1) = 1$. Show that $f '(X_0)$ = $2X_0$ for some $X_o \in [0,1]$

Tags: calculus

I tried to solve this problem using the Mean Value Theorem but didn't get very far. This question appeared in my calculus exam and I still can't solve it. Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: **Hint:** Look at $f(x)-x^2$ and use Rolle's theorem.

Comment: Thanks! how did you come up with f(x)-x^2?

Comment: Those equations are usually transferred to a root-finding problem, i.e. $f'(x_0)-2x_0 = 0$. This makes it easier to find solutions. Then i realized that the left side is the derivative of $f(x)-x^2$.

Comment: @LeBtz Thanks a lot that was pretty helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-x^2$ then $g$ is differentiable with 
$$g(0)=f(0)-0^2=0$$ and $$g(1)=f(1)-1^2=0$$ thus according to the **Mean Value Theorem** there exists $0<\color{red}{c}<1$ such that $g'(\color{red}{c})=0$ but
$g'(x)=f'(x)-2x$ and then $f'(\color{red}{c})-2\color{red}{c}=0$ , finally $f'(\color{red}{c})=2\color{red}{c}$.

Comment: @LeBtz Yes. Thanks.